# Is it ok to inject additional data into a module's scope? Or: What are the possibilities of managing/exposing module scoped state from/to the outside?

Tags: javascript, module, encapsulation, protected, accessor

I am designing Javascript modules using the Revealing Module Pattern. In my html I have `onmouseover="Test.OnLoad()"`. I need a callback after that is completed. I set the callback with `Test.Callback`. Is there a better way to do this? I basically need to write a lot of JavaScript modules and want to keep the functionality encapsulated. Thanks!

```js
const Test = (function () {
  const items = [];
  let callBack;

  function handleOnLoad() {
    items.push({ name: "Test" });
    callBack(items);
  }
  function setCallBack(cb) {
    callBack = cb;
  }

  return{
    OnLoad: handleOnLoad,
    CallBack: setCallBack
  };
}());

Test.CallBack(function(items) {
  console.log(`Item 0: ${ items[0].name }, items.length: ${ items.length }`);
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.test { display: inline-block; }
.test:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 88%!important; }
```

```html
<div class="test" onmouseover="Test.OnLoad()">mouseover test</div>
```

Comment: The above approach is one way of achieving the goal of a customizable callback with `items` access while keeping `items` entirely encapsulated within its module scope. Another approach could be a getter which exposes an (maybe even immutable) `items` copy into public. Any callback related implementation (if it was just for the sake o the `items` encapsulation) then was not necessary. Of cause one has to change the `mouseover` handling to something like `... .addEventListener('mouseover', () => { Test.onload(); customItemsHandling(Test.getItems()); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's approach is one way of achieving the goal of a customizable callback with `items` access while keeping `items` entirely encapsulated within its module scope.

Another approach could be a getter which exposes an <strike>(maybe even immutable)</strike> `items` copy into public. Any callback related implementation (if it was just for the sake o the `items` encapsulation) then was not necessary.

In order to not accidentally alter/mutate encapsulated data, it mostly already is good enough to not pass the encapsulated reference but a shallow copy of such data. Sometimes, and if appropriate/available, one might even pass a full [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).

Of cause one has to change the `mouseover` handling too ...

```js
const Test = (function () {
  const items = [];

  function handleOnLoad() {
    items.push({ name: `Test_${ items.length + 1 }` });
  }
  function getItems() {
    return (typeof structuredClone === 'function')
      && structuredClone(items) // a full `items` clone.
      || [...items];  // not the `items` reference ...
                      // but just a shallow copy of it.
  }

  return{
    OnLoad: handleOnLoad,
    getItems,
  };
}());

function logLastItemName(items) {
  console.log(`last item name: ${ items.at(-1).name }, items.length: ${ items.length }`);
}

function init() {
  document
    .querySelector('.test.event-listener')
    .addEventListener('mouseover', (/*evt*/) => {
      Test.OnLoad();
      logLastItemName(Test.getItems());  
    });
}
init();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.test { display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px; }
.test:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 88%!important; }
```

```html
<div
  class="test inline-script"
  onmouseover="Test.OnLoad(); logLastItemName(Test.getItems());"
>inline-script mouseover test</div>

<div class="test event-listener">event-listener mouseover test</div>
```

Letting modules feature exactly a single public function which creates custom callbacks is yet another way to go.

Maybe it's even the to be favored solution since one neither needs to inject any data into the module nor does one have to implement a getter function for a controlled `items` access.

The creator function takes a single argument, the custom function which later gets passed the `items` reference, and returns a function which is wrapped around the module's and the custom handler part.

Another advantage is the possibility to create as many customized but module or `items` related handlers as one is in need for.

```js
const Test = (function () {
  const items = [];

  function writeItem() {
    items.push({ name: `Test_${ items.length + 1 }` });
  }

  function createLoadHandler(customCallback) {
    return function handleLoad (/*evt*/) {

      writeItem();
      customCallback(items);
    }
  }

  return{
    createLoadHandler
  };
}());

function logLastItemName(items) {
  console.log(`last item name: ${ items.at(-1).name }, items.length: ${ items.length }`);
}
const customLoadHandler = Test.createLoadHandler(logLastItemName);

function init() {
  document
    .querySelector('.test.event-listener')
    .addEventListener('mouseover', customLoadHandler);
}
init();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.test { display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px; }
.test:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 88%!important; }
```

```html
<div
  class="test inline-script"
  onmouseover="customLoadHandler();"
>inline-script mouseover test</div>

<div class="test event-listener">event-listener mouseover test</div>
```